# Blank Blog Screen

Tags: design

I have a problem with my blog. When you view it on desktop, the page looks fine.
[image: Blog on Desktop]
However, if you view the "Customize" page, it looks like this:
[image: Customize Page]
And on mobile, the blog looks blank as well. Can you help me?
(Blog: http://atharvnadkarni.com/blog)

Comment: Are you running any plugins? Is that a default theme (ie, "Twenty {something}")?

Comment: @PatJ I am running 3 plugins (Enlighter, Easy Footnotes, WP Poll) and using Twenty Twenty-One theme. It is fixed now, I had to close the MathJax script tag, as suggested in the answer below. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mathjax script tag isn't closed properly:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" id="MathJax-script" async
  src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-chtml.js">
</head>
<body ... >
```

This means that the `</head>`, and the `<body>` and all of your page content is treated as text inside the `<script>` tag until you hit the `</script>` from your `document.body.classList.remove("no-js");`, and lost. (If you view page source in your browser you should be able to see this: the tags after your MathJax-script tag have no syntax highlighting.)

I don't know where that `<script>` tag came from but you should generate add a `</script>` close tag after it to close it properly.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" id="MathJax-script" async
  src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-chtml.js"></script>
```

Comment: How did you know I was using MathJax? That worked! Thank you very much! :-)